# Suported hardware (i.e. trackpad) and streaming? ASUS Zenbook UX305CA

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, asus, multi-touch

I'm on the verge to swap windows for ubuntu. However, I'm very, very green when it comes to basically all-things-computers. I won't be using the OS for anything but surfing, music and all them simple things. Never, ever got along with windows anyway.

I have, basically two questions;
1. Might seem like a small thing (but to me very important, since I have bad eyesight), I need to be able to make full use of the trackpad (ASUS smart gesture multitouche, no idea WHAT trackpad it is), most important is the zoom function, but also the two-finger-scroll. How can I see if it'd work?

2. I'm streaming Spotify > AVR via LAN (wi-fi). This is built into Spotify, so I can pick whatever device to stream to in the Spotify GUI. Would this work on ubuntu?

(Some) Laptop specs:
Intel M3 6Y30
8GB memory
Currently running Win- 10 on a 256gb SSD

Peace

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed 16.04 on a ASUS UX303UA. Everything I have tried so far has worked, except for one small glitch, which is that sometimes the wifi doesn't come back on after suspend. I've fixed that by adding a little script to the power management directory which works all the time.

I am just getting into configuring gestures. Right out of the box the ones I care about work, which are 2 finger scroll and two finger right click. Pinch to zoom doesn't seem to work as far as I can tell (and I could be wrong) but I don't care for it anyway (I never use it on my Macbook). Two finger scroll works better on 16.04 than it does on Win 10, especially because it doesn't do weird stuff Win 10 does like go to the switcher or the window background sometimes because it thought you swiped with 3 or 4 fingers instead of scrolling with 2 fingers.

As far as your Spotify question goes, I can't help - I've never used Spotify (I am pretty entrenched in the Google ecosystem). Sound works fine, I can play Youtube videos or listen to music on Google Play and it works as well as it does on Win 10. Casting music and video to my Chromecast works perfectly.

I would suggest that you put 16.04 on a USB stick and boot it up on your Zenbook and see how it works for you. I did that for a few days and I found it to be more pleasant to use than Win 10 was (the thing where it would sometimes go to the background window on a 2 finger scroll was making me crazy!) so I installed it dual boot with Win 10. So far the only reason I have found to need to boot Win 10 was to sync my Garmin watch. Once I finished that I went right back to 16.04

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the very good insight. So i could dualboot with windows to see how my hardware is supported? Peace